# tidying up and multiple event listeners

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to achieve a functional and DRY style of programming. In this case, I would need to somehow turn the "display" action into a function (which is a problem, since it makes particular outputs for every output),find a way to get rid of the global variable altogether and handle both click and keyword events at the same time to avoid the repetition of code. I can´t change the "id" tags or classes on the HTML, since they are part of the requested structure. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="drum-machine">
        <div id="display">
            <p id="displaytext"></p>
        </div>
            <div id="controls1">
            <button id="Heater1button"  class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id="Q" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>Q</button>
            <button id="Heater2button" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='W' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>W</button>
            <button id="Heater3button" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='E' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>E</button>
            </div>
        <div id="controls2">
            <button id="Heater4button" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='A' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>A</button>
            <button id="Heater6button"  class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='S'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3"></audio>S</button>
            <button id="OpenHHbutton"  class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='D'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3"></audio>D</button>
        </div>
        <div id="controls3">
            <button id="KicknHat" class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='Z'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3"></audio>Z</button>
            <button id="Kickbutton"class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='X'src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3"></audio>X</button>
            <button id="ClosedHHbutton"class="drum-pad"><audio class="clip" id='C' src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"></audio>C</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
var text1=document.getElementById("displaytext")

document.addEventListener("click",function(id) {
var id = event.target.id;
  switch (id) {
    case "Heater1button":
      document.getElementById('Q').play(), text1.textContent="Heater 1"
      break;
    case "Heater2button":
      document.getElementById('W').play(), text1.textContent="Heater 2"
      break;
    case "Heater3button":
      document.getElementById('E').play(), text1.textContent="Heater 3"
      break;
    case "Heater4button":
      document.getElementById('A').play(), text1.textContent="Heater 4"
      break;
    case "Heater6button":
      document.getElementById('S').play(), text1.textContent="Heater 6"
      break;
   case "OpenHHbutton":
    document.getElementById('D').play(), text1.textContent="Open HH"
    break;
    case "KicknHat":
      document.getElementById('Z').play(), text1.textContent="Kick N Hat"
      break;
    case "Kickbutton":
      document.getElementById('X').play(), text1.textContent="Kick"
      break;
      case "ClosedHHbutton":
      document.getElementById('C').play(), text1.textContent="Closed HH"
      break; 

  }
});


document.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
      switch(e.keyCode){
                    case 81: document.getElementById('Q').play(),text1.textContent="Heater 1"
break;
                    case 87: document.getElementById('W').play(),text1.textContent="Heater 2"
break;
                    case 69: document.getElementById('E').play(),text1.textContent="Heater 3"
break;
                    case 65: document.getElementById('A').play(),text1.textContent="Heater 4"
break;
                    case 83: document.getElementById('S').play(),text1.textContent="Heater 6"
break;
                   case 68: document.getElementById('D').play(),text1.textContent="Open HH"
break;

                   case 90: document.getElementById('Z').play(),text1.textContent="Kick N Hat"
break;
                   case 88: document.getElementById('X').play(),text1.textContent="Kick"
break;
                   case 67: document.getElementById('C').play(),text1.textContent="Closed HH"
break;
}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of refactoring your code, I'm going to show how I would write your code from scratch.

Select the target elements by className and convert the collection into a regular array:

```
const dps = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.drum-pad'));
const dt = document.querySelector('#displaytext');
```

Instead of using `switch` statements use arrays:

```
const texts = ["Heater 1", "Heater 2", "Heater 3", "Heater 4", "Heater 6", "Open HH", "Kick N Hat", "Kick", "Closed HH"];
const keycodes = [81, 87, 69, 65, 83, 68, 90, 88, 67];
```

Define a general handler for both `click` and `keydown` events and use `Array.prototype.indexOf` for finding the target element:

```
function handler(e) {
  const index = e.type === 'keydown' ? keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode) : dps.indexOf(this);
  const target = dps[index];
  if (!target) return;
  const audio = target.childNodes[0];
  audio.play();
  dt.textContent = texts[index];
}

dps.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', handler);
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
```

[A demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ynrvdos3/)

The above solution is an attempt to make the script shorter. It's not the only solution, of course. You can also use HTML5 data-* attributes instead of arrays.

Comment: But that doesn´t have the keyword event listener.

Comment: Yeah, missed that part. Didn't notice the scrollbar.

Comment: And not all display elements are called "heater", which would imply a lot of "else if" statements in your example, I think.

Comment: That´s actually awesome. Thanks!

Comment: if (!target) return makes sure nothing outside the array gets returned, right?

Comment: @HernanAriel You are very welcome. Yes. That line is necessary for avoiding errors. When users hit a key that is not supported, `.indexOf` returns `-1` and the `target` becomes `undefined`!

Comment: One more thing:   const audio = target.childNodes[0] why zero?

Comment: It selects the first child of the button element. `childNodes` is a collection of child nodes of an element. You can also code: `target.querySelector('audio')`

Comment: Sorry, one last question. The "This" inside the handler refers to index, right?

Comment: @HernanAriel No. As a click handler `this` in that context refers to the clicked element. As a keydown handler, `this` refers to the `document` object.